# How to check for existence of result

Tags: realm, realm-java

How can I check for the existence of a result and return `true` or `false`?

Currently I have:

```
boolean resultExists = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("name", "Bob").findFirst();
```

But this of course doesn't return a boolean. What do I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 boolean resultExists = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("name", "Bob").count() <= 0;
```

But you could just check if `findFirst` returned `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this using:

```
RealmQuery<User> query = _realm.where(User.class).equalTo("name", "Bob");
if(query.count() != 0L){
    RealmResults<User> users = query.findAll();
    // your business logic
}
```